# Stripe CLI ubutu installation issues

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

I want to install the Stripe CLI on ubuntu 20.04. I folled the step installation who there are in Stripe docs.

1. Download the latest linux tar.gz file from https://github.com/stripe/stripe- cli/releases/latest
2. Unzip the file: tar -xvf stripe_X.X.X_linux_x86_64.tar.gz
3. Run the executable: ./stripe

But when I tried to run the executable not working.

[image]

I try to install via apt-get install stipe whitout success
Any idea to install the stripe cli on ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Based on what I see on your terminal, stripe CLI installed properly. This is reflected by the fact that you were able to type `stripe login` with no `./` in front, and you did not get a command not found error. You may still be having trouble logging in but this does not seem to be an installation issue.

Answer (score 10):

If you haven't already figured out an answer to this question, you have to manually move the unzipped stripe program to usr/bin or usr/local/bin. I did personally did usr/local/bin so

```
(sudo) mv <filename> usr/local/bin
```

then ran

```
./stripe
```

and that worked.

Comment: I tried doing this but i got a message saying permissions denied, not allowed to paste files in this directory or something like that,  and yeah im the root user and all that.

Comment: Oops, mb for the late reply. If you were a root user there's no way your permission could be denied. Either just use `sudo mv`, or use `whoami` to see if you are a user or root user. If you aren't a root user, then you may log in/log out as a root user with `sudo -i` and `logout` respectively

Answer (score 7):

You have to login into your stripe dashboard first to start using stripe-cli.

On ubuntu you can run `./stripe login` to get logged in into your stripe dashboard.

Comment: One needs to run each command with `./stripe`, standing in the directory where the stripe file lies

Answer (score 0):

The installation method that you are using is the correct one, and recommended by the documentation:

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli#install

Have you paired your credentials as the documentation recommends? prompt should launch a browser that will allow you to do that. I would run `stripe login` without any parameters first, to make sure the account is paired.

Answer (score 0):

1 `wget` Download the latest linux tar.gz file from https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/releases/latest

2 Unzip the file: tar -xvf stripe_X.X.X_linux_x86_64.tar.gz

3 mv stripe ./usr/local/bin

4 **`./stripe login`**

5 `stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost:80/api/subs/stripe-webhook`