# Cannot Install Stripe CLI in Ubuntu AWS Cloud 9

Tags: ubuntu, stripe-payments, command-line-interface, cloud9

I am having trouble installing the Stripe CLI in Ubuntu AWS Cloud 9. First of all, no package manager (and especially not Homebrew) works so I manually downloaded and unzipped the stripe_1.8.10_linux_x86_64.tar.gz file in ~/environment/Downloads directory. Now according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67216143/stripe-cli-ubutu-installation-issues) I have to move ./stripe to the execution path.

What is the execution path and what command do I have to execute to accomplish this?

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67216143/stripe-cli-ubutu-installation-issues) was asked a year ago but was never resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have to move ./stripe to the execution path.

You don't have to move it to make it work.

> What is the execution path...

The execution path is nothing more than a directory accessible to you without entering the full path. You may leave `stripe` executable in the original directory (or move it anywhere for your choice) and add its path to the `$PATH` environment variable.

> ...and what command do I have to execute to accomplish this?

Run this command from where the stripe was unpacked:

```
sudo mv stripe /usr/local/bin
```

To avoid repeating unpacking and moving operations, you can simply use `dpkg`. Download [deb package](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/releases/download/v1.8.10/stripe_1.8.10_linux_amd64.deb) and install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i stripe_1.8.10_linux_amd64.deb
```

This is the basis for solving your troubles **inside Ubuntu.**
But unlike last year's question, you have a new specificity - **AWS Cloud9**.

I have doubts about this claim:

> First of all, no package manager

AWS Cloud9 is an IDE and of course the system package manager is not part of it. But AWS Cloud9 seats ontop Amazon EC2 instance and "[comes with a terminal that includes sudo privileges to the managed Amazon EC2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/)". Based on the title of your question, you are using Ubuntu. Ubuntu has `dpkg`. Hence, you have package manager. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: What I meant was Homebrew installation of the stripe CLI fails plus, after uninstalling, it leaves some lines in .profile that produce annoying warnings and need to be manually removed. The sudo mv stripe /usr/local/bin did the job so I am accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Download the needed version 
`curl -L https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/releases/download/v1.14.0/stripe_1.14.0_linux_x86_64.tar.gz > stripe.tar.gz`

After unarchiving it 
`tar -xvf stripe.tar.gz`

Remove unused archive 
`rm -f stripe.tar.gz`

Done ✅
Your stripe-cli is ready, try to check 
`./stripe --help`

Answer (score -1):

The "Linux" tab [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli#install) shows the steps for manual installation:

- Download the latest linux tar.gz file from https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/releases/latest
- Unzip the file: `tar -xvf stripe_X.X.X_linux_x86_64.tar.gz`
- Move `./stripe` to your execution path.

What that execution path is depends on your setup/environment.

The previous question you linked to does have multiple answers to the same effect.

Comment: This answer adds nothing new to the discussion.